# Java error when reading xml file

Tags: java, xml

I made a FileOutputStream, which saves an `arraylist` full of `String[]`'s to an xml file. The problem is, that when I load the file, I can only load it as a String. The Strings are some weird codes likes:

```
[Ljava.lang.String;@75a7d0f4
```

I need help to, save (or load) the `String[]`'s so I can call them probably

And, in the load method, I need to pass all the data to the `addSong()` method with a loop?

Code:

```
public class Songs {
List<String[]> songs = new ArrayList<String[]>();

public void addSong(String s, String a, String yt){
    String[] songarray= new String[3];
    songarray[0] = s;
    songarray[1] = a;
    songarray[2] = yt;
    songs.add(songarray);


}
public void editSong(int i, String s, String a, String yt){
    String[] editsongarray = new String[3];
    editsongarray[0] = s;
    editsongarray[1] = a;
    editsongarray[2] = yt;
    songs.remove(i);
    songs.add(i,editsongarray);
}
public void removeSong(int i){
    songs.remove(i);
}

public String[] getList(int i){
    String[] j = songs.get(i);
    return j;
}
public void save() throws FileNotFoundException{
    PrintWriter pw = new PrintWriter(new FileOutputStream("C:\\Applications\\songs.xml"));
    for(String[] x:songs)
        pw.println(x);
        pw.close();
}
public void load()throws FileNotFoundException{
    FileInputStream in = new FileInputStream("C:\\Applications\\songs.xml");
    Scanner scan = new Scanner(in);
    String x = scan.next();
    //String[] x = scan.next(); doesnt works 

    System.out.println(x);

}
```

}

Answer (score 2):

That's the default output when you print an array.  If you want to see the actual content use Arrays.toString()

Comment: Could be me misunderstanding something. But in my load method, i load the xml file as Strings.. The problem is pretty much i need to convert the String to an array(String[]) , or load the xml file as an array(String[]). Array.toString(), wouldt work on a String, right?? Thanks in advantage, i appreciate it :-)

Comment: If you want to parse xml use something like dom4j (easiest) or stax (better for really large xml documents but more complicated)

Answer (score 1):

You can not write the contents in to xml file as just plain strings. You need to follow the xml standards like

```
<songs>
   <song>song1</song>
   <song>song2</song>
<songs>
```

Also while reading you need to parse these `nodes` to extract the songs from the xml. There are quite a few API's to deal with xmls. You need to use them.

`Jdom` is one of the easy to use parsers. [Here](http://www.mkyong.com/java/how-to-read-xml-file-in-java-jdom-example/) is the simple example. You don't need to use the maven and all, you can download the jar from jdom website.